# Show dynamically-populated popup text when user hovers over spreadsheet cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet with a row that counts number from 1, 2, 3, etc. Each number stands for a certain kind of message (goal). These messages (goals) are in a different sheet and have text values.

Using a Google Apps Script, is it possible to make it so that if a user hovers over, for example, 1, they are shown the message that belongs to that value? I know that this is possible with notes, but that's not dynamic and not exactly what I mean.

I hope that someone has an idea on how to handle this.

[image]

Comment: Use the `setNote` method of `Range` class. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnotesnotes

Comment: Other than setting a note, there is no way for a script to modify the Sheets GUI to display pop-up data, at this time.

Answer (score 3):

Just use [`setNote`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnotesnotes) method of `Range` class. You can make notes dynamic in this way.

```
function noteSetter() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  // The size of the two-dimensional array must match the size of the range.
  var notes = [
     ["msg A1", "msg B1", "msg C1", "msg D1", "msg E1"],
     ["msg A2", "msg B2", "msg C2", "msg D2", "msg E2"]
  ];

  var cells = sheet.getRange("A1:E2");
  cells.setNotes(notes)
}
```

You can get messages to be displayed from another sheet using [`getValues`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) method of `Range` class.